# How to use Backbone.Model.save() promise with validation

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to use the promise returned from `Backbone.model.save()`.  Actually, per spec, it returns a promise if valid and false if not.  I'd like to use the return value, regardless of the type, in future `deferred.done()` and `deferred.fail()` calls.  Like this:

```
var promise = model.save();

$.when(promise).done(function() {
   console.log('success!');
});

$.when(promise).fail(function() {
   console.log('dang');
});
```

But, `$.when()` when passed a non-promise fires, `done()`, so, in the above, if the model is invalid, `$.when(false).done()` fires, and you get "success!".

I know I can use the `success` and `error` attributes in `save()`, but with my code, it's advantageous to have multiple `done()` functions applied later.  That's the power of the promise afterall.

So, I'm left with:

```
var promise = model.save();

if (promise) {
    $.when(promise).done(function() {
        console.log('success!');
    });

    $.when(promise).fail(function() {
        console.log('dang');
    });
} else {
    console.log('dang');
}
```

I hate not being DRY.

```
var promise = model.save();

var fail = function() {
    console.log('dang');
};

if (promise) {
    $.when(promise).done(function() {
        console.log('success!');
    });

    $.when(promise).fail(function() {
        fail();
    });
} else {
    fail();
}
```

Geting pretty messy.  You get the picture.  I'm hoping I'm just missing something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override Backbone.save method to have your desired behavior. If the returned value from the original save function is a boolean (which means validation failed), just return a custom promise and reject its related deferred.

```
var oldSaveFunction = Backbone.Model.prototype.save;
Backbone.Model.prototype.save = function(){
    var returnedValue = oldSaveFunction.apply(this, arguments),
        deferred = new $.Deferred();

    if(_.isBoolean(returnedValue)){
        deferred.reject();
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    return returnedValue;
}

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : 'http://www.google.com',
    validate : function(attributes){
         if(!("name" in attributes))
             return "invalid";
    }
});

var person = new Person();
$.when(person.save()).fail(function(){
   console.log("failed"); 
});
```

Try it on this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WNHXz/1/

Comment: Yeah, that seems straight forward.  I suppose I was most surprised by how `$.when()` handled `false`.  I'm sure there is a good reason that `false` should trigger `done()` instead of `fail()`.

Comment: Basically, any object that is not a promise will trigger `done()` instead of `fail()` in `jQuery.when method`. I think they didn't want to make assumptions or correlate a type with an error.

Comment: Coded more concisely, `Backbone.Model.prototype.save = function() {
 return oldSaveFunction.apply(this, arguments) || $.Deferred().reject().promise();
}`. Even better, the rejected promise should emulate a failed jqXHR.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improvement on a previous answer, but with better support for error handling. I needed it to avoid swallowing errors so here's what I did:

```
var oldSaveFunction = Backbone.Model.prototype.save;
Backbone.Model.prototype.save = function () {
  var returnedValue = oldSaveFunction.apply(this, arguments),
    fulfiller,
    rejecter,
    pendingPromise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      fulfiller = fulfill;
      rejecter = reject;
    });

  if (_.isBoolean(returnedValue)) {
    rejecter(this.validationError);
  } else {
    // Assuming returnedValue is a deferred
    returnedValue.then(function success() {
      fulfiller.apply(this, arguments);
    }, function failure(jqxhr, errorName, error) {
      rejecter(error);
    });
  }

  return pendingPromise;
};
```

Hope it helps!